# How to build Sparql query to get strings with space

Tags: java, sparql, jena

The below code is a part of big project, There are few records like hasName, hasAge, hasPlace and I am trying to build sparql query in java to get the record. The query works for names with no space between them. For instance: Alice, Bob.  But doesn't work for names with space between like: Joy Mik, Ervin pol.

```
SELECT ?statement ?name ?age ?place
WHERE
{ ?statement recordNS:hasName <http://example/base/name>
  ?statement recordNS:hasAge ?age
  ?statement recordNS:hasPlace ?place
```

}

The actual query:

```
public static getAllStatementsForPerson(String PersonName) {
  String queryString = 
      "PREFIX  defaultNS: <" + defaultNS + ">  " +
  "SELECT  ?statement ?age ?place "
  + "WHERE "
  + "{ ?statement defaultNS:hasname <" + defaultNS + PersonName + "> . " 
  + "?statement defaultNS:hasAge ?age " 
  + "?statement defaultNS:hasPlace ?place }";
  System.out.println("queryString is: " + queryString);
  Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
  QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, som);  // "som" is an ontology model
  try {
       ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();           
       while (results.hasNext()) {
              ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
   }
  } 
  catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
  finally {qexec.close();}
  return statements;
}
```

Anyone please help me, this is my first time asking for solution in this website... If I have done any mistakes please correct me.

Hear is the sample rdf file with few records....

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:defaultNS="http://Example/Base/Record_#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#Name"/>
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#Age"/>
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#Place"/>
    <rdf:Property rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#hasName"/>
    <rdf:Property rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#hasAge"/>
    <rdf:Property rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#hasPlace"/>

    <defaultNS:RecordStatement rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#statement001">
      <defaultNS:hasName>
        <defaultNS:Name rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#Alice"/>
      </defaultNS:hasName>
      <defaultNS:hasAge>
        <defaultNS:Age rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#26"/>
      </defaultNS:hasAge>
      <defaultNS:hasPlace>
        <defaultNS:Place rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#Europe"/>
      </defaultNS:hasPlace>    
    </defaultNS:RecordStatement>

    <defaultNS:RecordStatement rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#statement002">
      <defaultNS:hasName>
        <defaultNS:Name rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#Bob"/>
      </defaultNS:hasName>
      <defaultNS:hasAge>
        <defaultNS:Age rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#30"/>
      </defaultNS:hasAge>
      <defaultNS:hasPlace>
        <defaultNS:Place rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#Rome"/>
      </defaultNS:hasPlace>    
    </defaultNS:RecordStatement> 

    <defaultNS:RecordStatement rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#statement003">
      <defaultNS:hasName>
        <defaultNS:Name rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#JoyMik"/>
      </defaultNS:hasName>
      <defaultNS:hasAge>
        <defaultNS:Age rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#24"/>
      </defaultNS:hasAge>
      <defaultNS:hasPlace>
        <defaultNS:Place rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#Paris"/>
      </defaultNS:hasPlace>    
    </defaultNS:RecordStatement> 

    <defaultNS:RecordStatement rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#statement002">
      <defaultNS:hasName>
        <defaultNS:Name rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#ErvinPol"/>
      </defaultNS:hasName>
      <defaultNS:hasAge>
        <defaultNS:Age rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#36"/>
      </defaultNS:hasAge>
      <defaultNS:hasPlace>
        <defaultNS:Place rdf:about="http://Example/Base/Record_#StPetersburg"/>
      </defaultNS:hasPlace>    
    </defaultNS:RecordStatement> 
</rdf:RDF>
```

But my task is to change those name: "JoyMik", "ErvinPol" to "Joy Mik", "Ervin Pol"... So I build a query in sparql to get the records from rdf file...

```sql
PREFIX  defaultNS: <http://Example/Base/Record_#>
SELECT  ?statement ?name ?age ?place
WHERE {
  ?statement defaultNS:hasName <http://Example/Base/Record_#JoyMik> .
  ?statement defaultNS:hasAge ?age .
  ?statement defaultNS:hasPlace ?place
}
```

```
---------------------------------------
| Statement    | name   | age | place |
=======================================
| statement003 | JoyMik | 24  | Rome  |
---------------------------------------
```

But I want to change the name "JoyMik" to "Joy Mik" its giving an error at the above "queryString"... I thought I need to add something where it accepts white spaces.....

Comment: Do you mean in place of <http://example/base/name>?  URIs can not have spaces in them.  Check the data and see how it has been encoded: common ways are to replace with _ or to use %20.

Comment: Please show some of the data that you're querying against.  As Andy mentioned, spaces aren't allowed in URIs, so there shouldn't be things like `<http://example/base/Joy Mik>`.  If you show the data that you're querying against though (and if it's legal) we can show you how to adjust your query.

Comment: [Alice 26 Europe]     [Bob 30 Rome]     ["Joy Mik" 29 Paris]     ["Ervin pol" 36 "St. Petersburg"]     In this way how the records are present.

Comment: Is there any way like I can add underscore(_ 0r anythig) in query where there is a space in the recored.. like "Joy Mik" but the query takes it as "Joy_Mik".... its just my idea but is it possible.??????

Comment: @raj2103 "[Alice 26 Europe] [Bob 30 Rome] ["Joy Mik" 29 Paris] ["Ervin pol" 36 "St. Petersburg"]" is not RDF, it's some sort of plain text representation of something.  Show a sample of the RDF that you're querying.  E.g., show the results of `select ?s ?o { ?s recordNS:hasName ?o }` by editing your question and adding those results.  SPARQL will let you query any RDF data you have, but you haven't shown us any yet.  `<http://example/base/Joy Mik>` isn't a URI, and so by definition can't be a URI node in an RDF graph.  We need to see what your *actual* data is.

Comment: I cannot write the rdf file in comment box, so I wore it as another question at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134240/how-to-make-sparql-query-accept-white-spaces

Comment: @raj2103 If you have new information to add to the question click the `edit` link under your question and edit the existing question, please do not post a new duplicate question

Comment: I've migrated the content from that question into this question.  You probably didn't see the rdf content because it wasn't indented, and the markdown engine treated it as HTML markup (which got ignored).  Please delete the other question.

Comment: I have deleted the other question

Comment: I cannot provide the actual data but the above data is as same as the actual one and I have corrected the sparql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking how to "insert white spaces" in names and are looking for some way to do that in SPARQL. But that is the wrong way to approach this - instead, if you want to be able to query for names that have spaces in them, you should fix your RDF data.

As pointed out in the comments, URIs can not contain whitespaces. So obviously, you can not (easily) model names that contain spaces in RDF using only URIs. For this kind of thing, however, the RDF model provides [*literal* values](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-primer-20040210/#basicconcepts).

If we translate part of your RDF data to Turtle syntax (a bit easier to read and manipulate), your currently have this:

```
   <http://Example/Base/Record_#statement003> a defaultNS:RecordStatement ;
                         defaultNS:hasName <http://Example/Base/Record_#JoyMik> .
   <http://Example/Base/Record_#JoyMik> a defaultNS:Name .
```

One option is to make the model simpler: you are expecting the `hasName` property to contain a human-readable name, so you can just use a literal string instead of a URI to model it, and get rid of the `<http://Example/Base/Record_#JoyMik>` URI altogether, like so:

```
   <http://Example/Base/Record_#statement003> a defaultNS:RecordStatement ;
                         defaultNS:hasName  "Joy Mik"@en .
```

As you can see, we just add a string value directly, instead of a URI. The `@en` bit at the end, by the way, is optional: it's a language tag, which indicates the language the string is (in this case, English). You can leave that off if you don't want or need it.

Another  option is to keep the `<http://Example/Base/Record_#JoyMik>` URI, but to add a property to it that stores the string representation, for example like so:

```
   <http://Example/Base/Record_#statement003> a defaultNS:RecordStatement ;
                         defaultNS:hasName <http://Example/Base/Record_#JoyMik> .
   <http://Example/Base/Record_#JoyMik> a defaultNS:Name ;
                         rdfs:label "Joy Mik"@en .
```

This approach is a more complex model, but it also has advantages: in RDF, you can not easily say things *about* literal values: they are 'end points', as it were, in your graph. If you wish to be able to say things about the names of people (as opposed to about the people themselves), this is a good modeling choice.

How you then formulate a SPARQL query to get the names obviously depends on which modelling option you choose, but it should be straightforward to figure out in either case.

Comment: If I want to add the Place: "st. petersburg" do I need to add a property to <http://Example/Base/Record_#st.petersburg> that stores the string representation??

Comment: Yes, you do. More generally, I'd recommend you have a good look through an RDF tutorial (like the RDF Primer I'm linking to above), to get a feel for what RDF is and how to best use it to model your data.